# Is it possible to write a web server running in a modern browser such as Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari?

Tags: javascript, browser, webserver

In the Substratum Initial Coin Offering (ICO), the [White Paper](http://substratum.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/substratum_whitepaper.pdf) talks about solving problems of the current Internet, by allowing hosts to become web hosts.

Based on reading of the White Paper, the team looks like they're intending to write Javascript that runs on any modern browser (IE, Safari, Chrome, Firefox) on any platform (Windows, Linux, etc) to turn it into a web server.

As the White Paper is very general, I'm not sure if the team's Javascript is also having some form of access to uPnP technology that tells the nearest router to forward port 80 into the (supposed) web browser that's running on the web server.

Does anyone familiar with current web browsers know if browsers are capable of:

1. Providing access to uPnP that can tell routers to do port forwarding?
2. Running a web server using Javascript?

Thank you. (I'm familiar with general programming, just not capabilities of current web browsers. Please limit responses to capabilities of web browsers)

Comment: Check out the [Beaker Browser](https://beakerbrowser.com/) project.

Comment: Interesting, i know that chrome and some other browsers can do peer to peer and read and write files

Comment: Yes, the requirement is possible. There are several options available. There is an extension that is a web server at Chrome, Chromium. Opera is shipped with a built in web server. Have been mulling around a similar concept for a while [Using requestFileSystem to mirror local directories at server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391470/using-requestfilesystem-to-mirror-local-directories-at-server)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve own inquiry? Have you created a proof of concept for an implementation of requirement?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088586/building-web-server-using-chrome-socket-api, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899536/method-for-streaming-data-from-browser-to-server-via-http/

Answer (score 5):

A web browser normally cannot receive HTTP requests like a web server, but it can send and receive messages from other browsers via [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/). The [PeerServer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252484/975097) project simulates a web server in a browser in this way, using one browser as the "client" and the other as the "server."

There are some JavaScript libraries such as [nohost](https://github.com/humphd/nohost) that use Service Workers to mimic a file server on the client-side. This is apparently possible because service workers are able to [send custom responses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#custom_responses_to_requests) to HTTP requests.

It might even be possible to run a Linux server in a browser in an [x86 emulator in JavaScript](https://github.com/copy/v86), but I don't know if this has been done yet.

Comment: Demo x86. http://copy.sh/v86/